# from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist not working in Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am a beginner and trying to practice tensor flow using google colab. When I try to import in-build dataset available(mnist) in tensor flow ,I am getting below error.

Many users had this same problem in juypter notebook. I am using Google Colab to make use of free resource

**Code Snippet:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
 from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
 mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data", one_hot=True)
```

**Error:**

```
     ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent
  call last)   <ipython-input-4-4e25ee396bc7> in <module>()    ----> 1
  from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
        2 mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data", one_hot=True)

     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
  'tensorflow.examples.tutorials'
```

Someone please guide me to resolve this error.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

At the top write `!pip install mnist`. Use `import mnist`.
Then simply store the images and labels:

```
train_images = mnist.train_images() 
train_labels = mnist.train_labels()
test_images = mnist.test_images()
test_labels = mnist.test_labels()
```

That's it!!!

Answer (score -1):

```html
<html>
<body>
<div align="center"><p>I can't do that either</p></div>
<style>
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,400i,700");
div {
width : 400px;
height : 60px;
background-color : rgb(100,100,255);
border : 1px solid rgb(100,100,255);
box-shadow : 0 0 20px black;
border-radius : 24px;
font-family : Raleway, sans-serif;
transition : 1s;
text-align : center;
}
div:hover{
width : 420px;
height : 80px;

}
p{
margin-right : 20px;
color : white;
}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```